# How to disable the links before the jquery load is performed

Tags: jquery

I have below Jquery with me.

```
 $(".load-fragment").each(function()         
        {          
            var $objThis = $(this);
            var fname = $objThis.attr("href"); //Getting the href of the element
            var dynDivID = "divContent"+ $objThis.attr("id");  //Name of the dynamic div ID
            var newDiv = $("<div>").attr("id",dynDivID)
            .load(fname+ " #tab-container", {pupdate:"true"},function(response, status, xhr) 
            {               
                //Checking whether response contains class "formContainer" in it or not                
                if( $(response).filter('#tab-container').find('.formContainer').length ) 
                {      
                    ($objThis).unbind("click"); //Removing the attached click event                                                  
                }      
                else
                {
                $("#container-4").append(newDiv);//adding new div in div column2
                }           
                if (status == "error") 
                {               
                    newDiv.removeClass('dynDiv');
                    newDiv.addClass('errorDiv');
                }

            })//Loading page fragment from the given link
            .hide()//Hiding all the newly created DIVs
            .addClass('dynDiv')//Adding CSS to newly created Dynamic Divs
            .append($('<img/>').attr({ src: '/system/Images/ajax-loader.gif', alt: '', style:'margin:50px 0px 50px 185px' }));//Adding the loading.gif file

        });
```

Now I want to disable all other links till my JQuery Load is performed and once it is done then all other links starts working as usual.

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then the best think you can do is disable all links by default and in jquery ready function enable all these link.

Comment: Thanks but I can't do it as per requirement, just suggest how can I achieve in above code.